# Finding current display topology clone/extend if the primary monitor is in a extended mode

Tags: windows, winapi

This question has been asked many times but my configuration is a little different. To simply get the display config topology this code works well

But my internal (laptop) display is set to extended mode and other two monitors are set to clone mode, everytime I run this code it returns extended but my requirement is even if one monitor is set to clone I should get clone as output, irrespective of what the internal display is set to.

any pointers would be helpful..

````
UINT32 ModeArraySize = 0;
DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO* PathArray;
DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO* ModeArray;
DISPLAYCONFIG_TOPOLOGY_ID CurrentTopology;

GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes(QDC_ALL_PATHS, &PathArraySize, &ModeArraySize);

PathArray =   (DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO*)malloc(PathArraySize * sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO));
memset(PathArray, 0, PathArraySize * sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_PATH_INFO));

ModeArray =   (DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO*)malloc(ModeArraySize * sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO));
memset(ModeArray, 0, ModeArraySize * sizeof(DISPLAYCONFIG_MODE_INFO));

LONG ret = QueryDisplayConfig(QDC_DATABASE_CURRENT,&PathArraySize, PathArray, &ModeArraySize, ModeArray, &CurrentTopology);

free(PathArray);
free(ModeArray);```
````

Comment: How do you use [QueryDisplayConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig#examples) to [get the information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/relationship-of-mode-information-to-path-information)? Does [Enumeration and Display Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/enumeration-and-display-control?source=recommendations) work for you?

Answer (score 1):

According to [DISPLAYCONFIG_SOURCE_MODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-displayconfig_source_mode#members) and my test, **the cloning source surface position** is same as primary source surface position (0,0). However, When in extending mode, the other source surfaces extends surface.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. That could be one of the solution. In my case I saw the rectangular coordinates are also same for the cloned displays. I got the coordinates from EnumDisplayMonitors.

Comment: @AbhijitBorkakoty Any updates to the thread?

Comment: please see my comment above. I used the rectangular coordinates for the cloned monitors. They are same for any two cloned monitors.